# How to Remove the Hidden attribute from a text file

Tags: powershell

```
Powershell Version: 4.0
Operating System: Windows 7

"Error Report" | Set-Content $errorText
$getError = Get-Item $errorText 
$getError.Attributes ="Hidden"
```

I've created an error log file which will remain hidden unless their is an error. How would I remove the hidden attribute so that I could see my file? In other words what is the equivalent of right clicking the file, selecting properties, and unchecking hidden attribute in powershell?

Comment: `$getError.Attributes = "Normal"`

Comment: It's saying that it cannot find my file, I double checked the text file, it's there, just hidden.

Comment: Add the `-force` switch to the `Get-Item` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes property is of type `[System.IO.FileAttributes]`. Looking at [TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can see the valid options for setting attributes on file. As per the comments one option you have is no remove *all* attributes from the file/folder.

> **Normal** - The file is a standard file that has no special attributes. This attribute is valid only if it is used alone.

Be aware that this would potentially remove other attributes like `read-only` or `system`. In your case that might not be a concern but we need to be aware of the possibility.

The related second issue about using `Get-Item` on hidden files is solved by using the switch `-Force` and explained on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849788.aspx) as well.

> Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise be accessed, such as hidden items.

Knowing that we could do something like this:

```
$getError = Get-Item $errorText -Force
$getError.Attributes ="Normal"
```

Comment: Be aware that this would clear all other attributes. If you don't want that, clear only the hidden value by doing `$item.attributes = $item.attributes -bxor [io.fileattributes]::Hidden`